# Edit copyright in Hesita Child Theme

Tags: child-theme, copyright

I am currently using a Hesita Child Theme.
I want to edit the copyright text in the footer.

I have found the text I need to edit in 'hestia/inc/views/main/class-hestia-footer.php'

I think know what code to edit, however, I do not know how to make that change in the child theme. I have changed it before, but it has been reverted back to the original after a parent update.

Can anyone help?

Cheers

Comment: Have you set up a Child Theme? If not you might need to do that first. This way you can override certain files and a parent update won't destroy your edits. [A basic guide for setting up a child theme is in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You Could Also Try This Cheeky Little Trick :)

If you just want a quick and easy, no fuss change, you can do this to the [Hestia](https://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Hestia) theme copyright area.

Just add the following code to your child theme CSS or to the WordPress Customise > CSS area.

```
.copyright a {
    display: none;
}
.copyright:before {
    content: "My site";
}
.copyright:after {
    content: " Craig";
}
```

Alternatively, you could just hide it all.

```
.copyright {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible, but it will load (performance) and also will read via bots, search engines etc.

Answer (score 1):

The default Footer content of the parent theme Hestia is included via Hook `hestia_do_bottom_footer_content`. So you can remove them via [`remove_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action). and add your own content, own function in your child theme.

Source in the parent theme to valid this hook, file `hestia\inc\views\main\class-hestia-footer.php`:

```
/**
 * Initialization of the feature.
 */
public function init() {
    add_action( 'hestia_do_footer', array( $this, 'the_footer_content' ) );
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', array( $this, 'modify_footer_menu_classes' ) );
    add_action( 'hestia_do_bottom_footer_content', array( $this, 'bottom_footer_content' ) );
}
```

The content is inside this method:

```
/**
 * Function to display footer copyright and footer menu.
 * Also used as callback for selective refresh.
 */
public function bottom_footer_content() {
    $hestia_general_credits = get_theme_mod(
        'hestia_general_credits',
        sprintf(
            /* translators: %1$s is Theme Name, %2$s is WordPress */
            esc_html__( '%1$s | Powered by %2$s', 'hestia' ),
            sprintf(
                /* translators: %s is Theme name */
                '<a href="https://themeisle.com/themes/hestia/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">%s</a>',
                esc_html__( 'Hestia', 'hestia' )
            ),
            /* translators: %1$s is URL, %2$s is WordPress */
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%1$s" rel="nofollow">%2$s</a>',
                esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org', 'hestia' ) ),
                esc_html__( 'WordPress', 'hestia' )
            )
        )
    );

    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location' => 'footer',
            'depth'          => 1,
            'container'      => 'ul',
            'menu_class'     => 'footer-menu',
        )
    );
    ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $hestia_general_credits ) || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
        <div class="copyright <?php echo esc_attr( $this->add_footer_copyright_alignment_class() ); ?>">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $hestia_general_credits ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: See: https://atechplanet.wordpress.com/2018/05/13/remove-footer-credit-hestia/

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in editing the copyright and not removing it I would recommend using the [theme_mod filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_mod_name/). Just play with the `$new_credits` variable in the example below which works in the child functions.php file.

```
function wp739534_change_hestia_copyright( $old_credits ){

    $new_credits = sprintf(
    /* translators: %1$s is Theme Name, %2$s is WordPress */
        esc_html__( '%1$s | Powered by %2$s', 'hestia-pro' ),
        sprintf(
        /* translators: %s is Theme name */
            '<a href="https://themeisle.com/themes/hestia/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">%s</a>',
            esc_html__( 'Hestia', 'hestia-pro' )
        ),
        /* translators: %1$s is URL, %2$s is WordPress */
        sprintf(
            '<a href="%1$s" rel="nofollow">%2$s</a>',
            esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org', 'hestia-pro' ) ),
            esc_html__( 'WordPress', 'hestia-pro' )
        )
    );

    return $new_credits;
}
add_filter( 'theme_mod_hestia_general_credits', 'wp739534_change_hestia_copyright' );
```

Answer (score -1):

In the child-theme, you must duplicate a file class-hestia-footer.php like as parent-theme and edit file in child-theme.

Comment: I have tried that, however, it does not work :(

Comment: Depends on how the file is loaded. The method only works for system files (home.php, single.php, ..). It's very unlikely to work for /inc/views/main/class-hestia-footer.php